# How would I effectively lock a room for a text based game?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using python 2.7 for this game. I have looked at other answers and questions similar to this but since I'm a python beginner with some experience with python I don't really understand some of the answers and some of the answers I saw weren't that clear. Because of the current code I have, it created a problem where when I got the item necessary to unlock the room it says the room has not been found. This is the code:

```
## checks which connecting rooms player.currentRoom has available and updates currentRoom on player choice.
def navigate(player,enemyToken):
    os.system("clear")

    # print available rooms to navigate to
    i = 0
    for room in player.currentRoom.connectingRooms:
        print(str(i) + ": " + room.name)
        i = i + 1

    try:
        navigate = input("Choose room to navigate to [type its number]: ")

        # change players current room to selected room and contains the locking code after the "and".
        if(navigate <= len(player.currentRoom.connectingRooms) and player.items[0].unlocks == room == True): 
            player.currentRoom = player.currentRoom.connectingRooms[navigate]
        else:
            print("room not found!")
            time.sleep(1)
    except NameError:
        print("that was not a number!")
        time.sleep(1)
    except SyntaxError:
        print("that was not a number!")
        time.sleep(1)
    except IndexError:
        print("that was not an option!")
        time.sleep(2)
```

how would I make a lock that would succesfully lock the player from accessing that room untill they have grabbed the object that is required to open this room. If you need more code to help me I would provide it.

Comment: "when I tested it out it didn't work and created a new problem": Please explain: what *should* have happened, what *actually* happened, and what *new problem* was created?

Comment: The only idea that I have is to use an if, else in a while condition to make it so it checks if you have the item and will then allow you to go if you need an example I will be happy to oblige.

Comment: @TommyLawrence could you write an answer to explain you idea a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my comment, this code should word(Untested as I do not know where the locking mechanism should go)

Code:

```
x = True
while x = True:
    if LockRoom != RoomUnlock:
        Code here
    else:
        Code here when you unlock the room
        x = False
```

Comment: The function which I put on the question description and under the " # change players current room to the selected room and contains the locking code after the "and"". That's were it's suppose to go.

Answer (score 1):

> player.items[0].unlocks == room == True

This part looks weird to me. player.items[0].unlocks == room should be sufficient to check if the two numbers match.